# Which auto-scaling database can I use with Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I will start an app on the App Engine, I know that there are a lot of option of databases to connect.

But I would like to know which is the best auto-scalable database solution for App Engine?
Is a NoSQL DB? Which is the name on the Cloud Console?

I read that I can use "Cloud Firestore in Datastore Mode", is it a good solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is growing list of database solution form Google (please check [here](https://cloud.google.com/products/databases)).

If you need NoSQL and automatically scaled solution you can choose from:
Firestore, Firestore in Datastore Mode and Big Query database it will depend of what the app will be doing.

Historically Firestore is new version of Datastore. "Firestore in Datastore mode" is version of Firestore that provide backward compatibility with previous version of Datastore. ([Google doc about it](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/firestore-or-datastore)).

Firestore is document based NoSql, while Datastore is based on entities and kinds.

As I understand the app will be build from scratch so I think you should use resent version so I think Firestore in Native mode should be a choice. Personally, for me, document based NoSql is more natural and easy deal with.

Please go trough Google documents I have added. You should find everything there.
I hope it will help.

Comment: thank you so much! I read your links. In the first one, two characteristics ("Scale insurance" and "Serverless") basically defined which database I need. How my app is a middleware to connect the ecommerce orders with the backoffice software, "Firestore in Datastore mode" sounds like the best choice based in the second link.